# Combining recursion with a loop to find maximal value

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, recursion

I am trying to solve a recursion exercise and get really confused.
the question is as follows:

let's say i have an apartment which is n squared meters,
i = [1,2,3..., n] are units of square meters, and [p1, p2, p3, ..., pn] are the corresponding prices per square meter (for ex. p1 is the price for 1 squared meter, and pn is the price for n squared meters).

I want to find the optimal way to divide my apartment which will give me the "maximal income".

Example - if i have 4 squared meter apartment, and the price list for the sizes 1,2,3,4 are correspondingly [1,5,8,9], then these are the set of options:

- leave the apartment as one 4 squared meter unit (value: 9)
- split the 4 square meters into 1,1,1,1 square meters (total value: 4)
- split the 4 square meters into 1,1,2 square meters (total value: 7)
- split the 4 square meters into 2,2 square meters (total value: 10)
- split the 4 square meters into 1,3 square meters (total value: 9)

therefore my function "profit" should return the number 10 for the input:
profit([1,5,8,9], 4)

i have been asked to solve this using the following pattern where recursion calls must be only inside the loop:

```
def profit(value, size):
    ...
    for i in range(size):
        ...
    return ...
```

i managed to solve this without the loop condition after a very long time, but it really frustrates me how hard and un-intuitive recursion function are.
i would really appreciate general guidance tips for these kind of question, or even if you can refer me to other sources which might help me learn this topic better. it's too hard for me to follow sometimes.

and of course, would appreciate your help with this specific function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using the following function:

```
def profit(value,size):
    if size <= 0:
        return 0
    lst1 = []
    for i in range(size):
        lst1.append(profit(value, size-(i+1))+value[i])
    return max(lst1)
```

Comment: Nice! Looks a lot cleaner than what Ajax was suggesting

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that finds the possible combinations of the range of the square size. Then, for each combination that sums to four, the maximum floor size can be found:

```
def profit(value, size):
  def combinations(d, _size, current = []):
    if sum(current) == _size:
      yield current
    else:
      for i in d:
        if sum(current+[i]) <= _size:
          yield from combinations(d, _size, current+[i])
  options = list(combinations(range(1, size+1), size))
  prices = dict(zip(range(1, size+1), value))
  result = max(options, key=lambda x:sum(prices[i] for i in x))
  return sum(prices[i] for i in result)

print(profit([1,5,8,9], 4))
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the same format as the original question, which I'm assuming was a template for the problem that @Limitless is not allowed to change, your recursive function takes 3 arguments

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe The recursive function can be wrapped with another function containing the desired signature. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: i'm afraid @ChristianScillitoe is right, but thanks!

Comment: @Ajax1234 in your code profit() is not a recursive function. It never calls itself. Limitless was asking for a recursive solution.

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe The solution is recursive, however, it is `profit` that calls the recursive `combinations` function

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give you the full answer, since this seems like it could be an assignment. However, I will try to push you in the right direction as to why recursion is optimal here. I've added one line of code to your example that I think will help you out. Before adding it to your code, I suggest you try to completely wrap your head around what is happening here.

```
def profit(value, size):
    for i in range(size):
        # Get the profit of the size before this combined with a 1
        profit(value, size - 1) + profit(value, 1)
```

If you're having trouble understanding why this is useful, feel free to leave a comment and I can give you a more in depth explanation later.

EDIT:

A key concept to keep in mind when implementing a recursive function are your base cases.

In this example, you already know what the values are for each size, so incorporate that into your solution.

```
def profit(value, size):
    # BASE CASE
    if size == 1 :
        return value[0]

    # Size > 1
    for i in range(size):
        # Return the maximum value of all given combinations.
        return max(value[size], profit(value, size - 1) + profit(value, 1))
```

This is an almost complete solution now, there's just one piece missing.

Hint: This code currently fails to test profit(value, 2) + profit(value, 2) (which happens to be the maximum profit in this scenario)

Comment: i can see how this:

    for i in range(size):
        profit(value, size-(i+1))

helps me to iterate over all the combinations, but I still encounter the problem of summing the values within the recursion, i don't know how to approach this..